# Eclipse - Close tabs to the right

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there a plugin or some way to get a behaviour of close tabs to the right, like the chrome browser?

Close others allows you to keep only one single file open afterwards.

Close tabs to the right is essential, as it allows you to place files that are **important on the left side**, and then whenever you open tabs, you can still keep those that are important when closing the others, the right ones.

Comment: Eclipse Mars 4.5 will have that feature! See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28542905/6309

Comment: That's a welcome improvement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Close all tabs to the right" option in eclipse java editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102236/close-all-tabs-to-the-right-option-in-eclipse-java-editor)

Answer (score 7):

I don't think there's a plugin for that.

As an alternative, you could do `CTRL+SHIFT+E` to bring up the "Switch to Editor" dialog. From there, you could select all the editors to the "right" of your active tab and click `Close Selected Editors` to close them. It's not as fast as what you wanted but it lets you organize your tabs the way you want to (i.e. important tabs to the left).

Comment: Oh yeah, they're organized by name, my bad. I guess there's really no easy solution for the behavior you want, then.

Comment: Mm, like everything else in Eclipse.