# "Close all tabs to the right" option in eclipse java editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Does anyone know if there is any plugin for "closing all tabs to right functionality" available for java editor?

example: Like chrome browser!

Comment: Eclipse Mars 4.5 will have that feature! See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28542905/6309)

Answer (score 4):

This is monitored in [bug 337588](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=337588), and has just been closed (February 2015, by [**Andrey Loskutov (`iloveeclipse`)**](https://github.com/iloveeclipse), [commit ca6d410](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/commit/?id=ca6d410cf1d3749c9a3727ea17620f5b9ef39db2) also [visible on the GitHub mirror](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/commit/ca6d410cf1d3749c9a3727ea17620f5b9ef39db2), [code review](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/41685/)), planed for Eclipse Mars 4.5 M6.

> Added "`Close Tabs To The Left`" and "`Close Tabs To The Right`" menus to the tab area below "`Close Others`" and above "`Close All`".
>   The menus appear only if there is at least one tab on the appropriate side from the current tab.
>   Added extra separator before "`Close All`" to have visual highlight between close "`some`" and close "`all`" menus.

[image: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-7EIL9NhrNLM/VOHo50-bTMI/AAAAAAAABY8/cDZhmruaWak/w1208-h570-no/close.png]

<sup>(picture from [Lars Vogel](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+LarsVogel)'s [post on Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+LarsVogel/posts/TK5FDBoy1dE))</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, I do not believe so. It would not be hard to create a custom command to close editors in either direction of the selected editor however as of Eclipse Juno 4.1 I don't believe there is an API that allows you to contribute a action/command to the context menu of a view or editor but they are working on providing one soon, here is a link to the feature request in the Eclipse bug tracking system.

[Context Menu API Contribution Feature Request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=387233)

On possible solution is to add an action to the toolbar that performs the action you want but would not be as convenient as right clicking on the editor tab. If that works, let me know and I'll write the code for a plugin that does that.

Hope that helps - Duncan